# Test if element exists jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to see if  exists in any of these uls. I tested it with .length but I'm not sure if I'm doing this right. It alerts yes even if there are is no li with the select-sub-domain class.

http://jsfiddle.net/ST8Be/

```
if ($('ul.expul > li.select-sub-domain').length < 0) {
var sub_doma = "Not set";
alert("no");
} else {
alert("yes");
var sub_domain = $('li.select-sub-domain').attr('id');
var sub_domainSplit = sub_domain.split('-');
var sub_doma = sub_domainSplit[1];
}​

<ul class="one expul">
<li class='select' id=eng-88>1</li>
<li class='select' id=eng-89>2</li>
<li class='select' id=eng-90>3</li>
<li class='select' id=eng-91>4</li>
<li class='select' id=eng-92>5</li>
<li class='select' id=eng-93>6</li>
<li class='select' id=eng-94>7</li>
<li class='select' id=eng-95>8</li>
<li class='select' id=eng-96>9</li>
<li class='select' id=eng-97>10</li>
<li class='select' id=eng-98>11</li>
<li class='select' id=eng-99>12</li>                    
</ul>

<ul class="two expul hide">
 <li class='select' id=fin-100>1</li>
<li class='select' id=fin-101>2</li>
<li class='select' id=fin-102>3</li>
<li class='select' id=fin-103>4</li>
<li class='select' id=fin-104>5</li>
<li class='select' id=fin-105>6</li>
<li class='select' id=fin-106>7</li>
<li class='select' id=fin-107>8</li>                
</ul>

<ul class="three expul hide">
 <li class='select' id=three-108>1</li>
 <li class='select' id=three-109>2</li>
 <li class='select' id=three-110>3</li>
 <li class='select' id=three-111>4</li>
 <li class='select' id=three-112>5</li>
 <li class='select' id=three-113>6</li>
</ul>​
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change `$('ul.expul > li.select-sub-domain').length > 0)`

to `$('ul.expul > li.select-sub-domain').length == 0)`

You are code like if length is greater than 0, alert no. Which is not correct.

It should alert no when length is equal to 0.

Comment: Thank you. Missed that one :)

Answer (score 0):

Just change your If statement, right now you are alerting yes when there is no items and no when there are none.

```
if ($('ul.expul > li.select-sub-domain').length === 0) {
   var sub_doma = "Not set";
   alert("no");
} else {
   alert("yes");
   var sub_domain = $('li.select-sub-domain').attr('id');
   var sub_domainSplit = sub_domain.split('-');
   var sub_doma = sub_domainSplit[1];
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PeterForss/ST8Be/2/

**EDIT:** 
Because [0 in JavaScipt is falsy,](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_boolean.asp) it can be written even shorter, like this:

```
if ($('ul.expul > li.select-sub-domain').length) {
   alert("yes");
   var sub_domain = $('li.select-sub-domain').attr('id');
   var sub_domainSplit = sub_domain.split('-');
   var sub_doma = sub_domainSplit[1];
} else {
   var sub_doma = "Not set";
   alert("no");
}​
```